Plot linear mixed-effects model results
Background: I am looking at how clinical factors affect disease progression in a longitudinal dataset with a mixed effects linear model where A is the response variable (here, a measure of disease) and B the clinical factors I want to study:
lmer(A ~ B1 + B2 + B3 + time + (time | person))
Problem: I want to plot the residuals per person of the model versus B1, i.e.:
plot(x=B1, y=residuals_per_person(lmer(A ~ B2 + B3 + time + (time | person))))
B1 is constant within each patient, so in a cohort of 1000 patients I want a plot with 1000 x values and 1000 y values.
My attempt: I tried getting the random effect slopes of the model and using those as y:
y = ranef(lmer(A ~ B2 + B3 + time + (time | person)))$person[,2] #this gets the slopes
plot(y ~ B1)
However, when I use this approach I get a similar p-value for B1 (in the model lm(y ~ B1)) as when using a linear slopes approach for the analysis, i.e.:
slopes = lm(slope_of_A_per_person_over_time ~ B2 + B3)$residuals
finalmodel = lm(slopes ~ B1)
Here, B1, which was significant in the linear mixed-effects model, is not significant at all.
Final questions: I have 2 questions, of which Q1 is most important:
Q1: Can I plot the residuals per patient vs B1 in a way that reflects the results from the mixed-effects model (i.e. where the slope is the effect size?), and if so how?
Q2: Why are the results so different for B1 between the linear mixed-effects model approach and the slopes method, even when using slopes from the mixed-effects model?
I have used both glmmTMB and lme4 in R so can use either to solve this problem.

Welcome to CV!  It looks like , in part, you are comparing a model with random slopes to a two stage approach where use just regular regression.  Is that accurate?  Some context about the goal would help.

Also writing things in the format of model <- function() then eg ranef(model) makes it easier to read

Welcome to CV. Questions about code are off topic here, but, in general. R models have a $residuals which you should be able to use.

@NBrouwer Thanks! In part – I am using the model with random slopes but just want to understand why results are so different (in terms of p-value and effect size of covariate B1) between the two stage approach and random slopes approach. I understand that mixed-effects models resample the slopes so they won't be comparable to slopes from a linear model, but when using the random effect slopes in a two-stage approach I still get very different results compared with the 1-stage mixed-effects model (which I thought was just looking at the effect of covariates on the random effects slope?).

@PeterFlom Thanks – yes I have tried using residuals() or $residuals but the function gives me residuals for every point in the longitudinal dataset rather than 1 for each person. I would need 1 residual per patient to plot residuals vs B1 because B1 is a variable that is fixed for a person across their datapoints (like eye colour).

Partial answer - if sample sizes are unequal then the random slopes and two stage models will differ.  Also to get the residuals you want you may need to generate predictions from the model since what the model normally gives you are obs level residuals.  What you get from ranefs()  are estimated coefficients for eg slopes.  You could compare these to the slopes from a two stage model (sorry, this last bit may not address your questions)
